# How to fix: ThisDocument.Close freezes MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Why is following code running from MS Word (MailMerge main document) freezing the application on `ThisDocument.Close False`?

Do I need to close the `Scripting.Dictionary` in some way other than setting the object to `nothing`?

There is only one instance of Word active, it is visible, `ThisDocument` is not the active document.
I am even explicitly activating the last opened document, even if it is already active. Not sure if I even need to set the `oWorkbook` and `oExcel` to `nothing`.

```vb
Sub MailMergeAlternative()

    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oWorkbook As Object
    Dim oFirstCell As Object   
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set oWorkbook = oExcel.workbooks.Open(SOUBOR)
    Set oFirstCell = oWorkbook.sheets(SESIT).Cells(1, 1) 

    Dim Dict As Object
    Set Dict = MakeDictionary() ' Scripting.dictionary

    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim Radek As Long
    Dim Radku As Long
    Radku = oFirstCell.currentregion.Rows.Count    

    For Radek = 2 To Radku
        ' ... fill Dict, use MailMerge to create new document for active record ...
        Set oDoc = ActiveDocument ' the new document after MailMerge
        ' ... insert values, save the new document, do not close it ...
    Next

Closing:
    oDoc.Activate           '  <== set to active, not needed
    Set Dict = Nothing
    oWorkbook.Close
    oExcel.Quit
    Set oWorkbook = Nothing ' probably not needed, closed above
    Set oExcel = Nothing    ' probably not needed, closed above

    ThisDocument.Close False ' <== Problem

End Sub
```

**Expected:** 
The code runs, creates new document(s) and closes the document which is containing the macro and from where it was called. The last active document stays open (the newly created one), or if nothing was created, Word app closes.

**What is happening:**
The document closes, the last active document stays open. But Word freezes and the document needs to be found in Task Manager and "brought to foreground". This is not a problem when using MailMerge alone (with additional vba work) and seems to be connected to use of Excel and `Scripting.Dictionary`.

Comment: Don't use `ThisDocument` - that object is the document that contains the code. If it's the `oDoc` object that should be closed use that object.

Comment: No, I need to close the document containing the code. This is what I intend to do.
The oDoc is the new, active document, created by the code.

Comment: Trying to close the document running the code is why the error is occurring. If the document is closed, then the code cannot finish correctly.

Comment: @CindyMeister just to get a confirmation: it cannot be done from single document, it needs a workaround solution - getting the close command from somewhere outside. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't provide a [mcve] so that we can test exactly what you're doing it's possible that the following solution won't work for your exact environment. My test was run on the code below, which essentially creates a number of new documents then closes a document. (I have no access to your Excel content or to `MakeDictionary()`)

I created a template (dotm) and put the code in that, closed it, created a new document from the template. This document has access to the code, via its link to the template. Closing the document will also release the template (unless another document based on it is opened). But in my test the code finished without an error.

```
Sub TestCloseSelfDocument()
    Dim docMmMainMerge As Word.Document

    Set docMmMainMerge = ActiveDocument
    Dim Dict As Object

    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim Radek As Long
    Dim Radku As Long
    Radku = 5

    For Radek = 2 To Radku
        Documents.Add
        ' ... fill Dict, use MailMerge to create new document for active record ...
        Set oDoc = ActiveDocument ' the new document after MailMerge
        ' ... insert values, save the new document, do not close it ...
    Next

Closing:
    Set Dict = Nothing

    docMmMainMerge.Close False     
End Sub
```